# HTTP client error 403

Tags: delphi, httpclient, http-status-code-403, indy10

I have the following problem: when I click a button on a site (`http://domain-location.com`) I receive information back to me and the url is changed to `http://domain-location.com?key=value`.
I want to create a sample http client to receive information easily. Here is my code:

```
function DoRequest(aVal: string): string;
 const DOMAIN = 'http://domain-location.com';
 var
   request: TIdHTTP;
   responseStream: TMemoryStream;
   responseLoader: TStringList;
   urlRequest: string;
 begin
   request := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
   responseStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
   responseLoader := TStringList.Create;

   try
     try
       // accept ranges didn't help
       // request.Response.AcceptRanges := 'text/json';
       // request.Response.AcceptRanges := 'text/xml';
       urlRequest := DOMAIN + '?key=' + aVal;
       request.Get(urlRequest, responseStream);
       responseStream.Position := 0;
       responseLoader.LoadFromStream(responseStream);
       Result := responseLoader.Text;
     except on E: Exception do
       Result := e.Message;
     end;
   finally
     responseLoader.Free;
     responseStream.Free;
     request.Free;
   end;
 end;
```

**EDIT** After the first answer I edited my function (still not working):

```
 function DoRequest(aVal: string): string;
 const DOMAIN = 'http://domain-location.com';
 var
   request: TIdHTTP;
   responseStream: TMemoryStream;
   responseLoader: TStringList;
   urlRequest: string;
   uri: TIdURI;
 begin
   request := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
   responseStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
   responseLoader := TStringList.Create;
   request.CookieManager := TIdCookieManager.Create(request);
   uri := TIdURI.Create(DOMAIN);

   try
     try
       // accept ranges didn't help
       // request.Response.AcceptRanges := 'text/json';
       // request.Response.AcceptRanges := 'text/xml';
       urlRequest := DOMAIN + '?key=' + aVal;
       request.CookieManager.AddServerCookie('cookie1', uri);
       request.CookieManager.AddServerCookie('cookie2', uri);
       request.CookieManager.AddServerCookie('cookie3', uri);
       request.Get(urlRequest, responseStream);
       responseStream.Position := 0;
       responseLoader.LoadFromStream(responseStream);
       Result := responseLoader.Text;
     except on E: Exception do
       Result := e.Message;
     end;
   finally
     responseLoader.Free;
     responseStream.Free;
     request.Free;
   end;
 end;
```

And after I do the request the result is: `HTTP1.1 403 Forbidden`.
I inspected the page and the button I click is in a form like this:

```
<form action="http:/domiain.com" method="GET">
   <input type="text" name="key">
   <input type="submit" value="Click">
</form>
```

When I type `http://domain-location.com?key=value` there is no problem.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Is the passed `aVal` parameter value URL encoded ? If not, and it's needed, wrap it by `urlRequest := DOMAIN + '?key=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode(aVal);`.

Comment: I tried `TIdURI.ParamsEncode(aVal)` but didn't help

Comment: I added `request.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';` right after `try` but didn't help

Comment: @TLama, OP is using `GET`.

Comment: @TLama, But surely the webbrowser is not sending extra `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if OP states that `When I type http://domain-location.com?key=value there is no problem` - I'm assuming he "type" it in a web-browser. Id check for cookies/UserAgent. the HTTP request should be sniffed to see what exactly is being posted/received...

Comment: @kobik, taking back my comment(s). You're probably right about user agent.

Comment: @TLama, or some other HTTP header... see common cases for [`403 forbidden`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).

Comment: @kobik the problem was with the UserAgent. Thank you for the answer

Comment: Welcome :) It was a comment actually. rather than editing your own question, please post an answer and accept it. I'm also not sure, is the line `request.Get(DOMAIN, TStream(nil));` needed? if yes, then a cookie is also involved.

Comment: @mitko.berbatov please take a look here [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)

Comment: You might rollback your question to revision 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was with the UserAgent:

```
function DoRequest(aVal: string): string;
  const DOMAIN = 'http://domain-location.com';
var
  request: TIdHTTP;
  urlRequest: string;
begin
  request := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);

  try
    try
      request.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36';
      urlRequest := DOMAIN + '?key=' + aVal;
      Result := request.Get(urlRequest);
    except on E: Exception do
      Result := e.Message;
    end;
  finally
    request.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

If cookies are involved, then you should `GET` the original HTML page first so the server can send whatever cookies it needs to be posted back when the button is "clicked", then you can `GET` the next page and let `TIdHTTP` post whatever cookies it had received.

Try this:

```
function DoRequest(const aVal: string): string;
const
  DOMAIN = 'http://domain-location.com';
var
  request: TIdHTTP;
begin
  try
    request := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      request.Get(DOMAIN, TStream(nil)); // get cookies, discard HTML
      Result := request.Get(DOMAIN + '?key=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode(aVal));
    finally
      request.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Result := e.Message;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: what's with that `TStream(nil)` thing? shouldn't a simple `request.Get(DOMAIN)` do the job, or you force an overload this way or what?

Comment: `request.Get(DOMAIN)` calls the `function Get(AURL: string): string` method, which returns a decoded `String` of the response data. In this example, that data is not being used, so preparing that `String` is wasted overhead. I call the `procedure Get(AURL: string; AResponseContent: TStream)` method instead, setting the `TStream` parameter to `nil`, to discard the response data and avoid the overhead of allocating memory and performing decode logic.

Comment: I tested it. The exception is raised on this line `request.Get(DOMAIN, TStream(nil));`

Answer (score 3):

Check the actual request that is sent by your browser.  403 suggests that there is some sort of authentication going on.  This might be a token or a cookie that your browser has, and sends with the request, but your sample client application may not have.  Open the browser debugging panel to check the get request made by your browser, and compare it to the one made by your application.  I bet there will be some difference.